# -bash: cd: .ssh/: Permission denied

Tags: ssh, permissions, ls

When I type in `cd .ssh` in terminal, it returns with `-bash: cd: .ssh/: Permission denied`. Now I cannot add my ssh keys to ssh.

When I type `ssh-add ~/.ssh/idname` it says `/Users/Dan/.ssh/idname: Permission denied`.

I think it has to do with me typing `ls -d` because it worked before I typed this into terminal?

Comment: What is the output of `id;ls -ld ~/.ssh`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you have "Permission denied" on a directory, it is likely that the directory does not have execute permissions.  Similarly, to traverse a directory tree to get at a file, you would need execute permissions on each directory in between the root and the file (hence the same error for the other command).

Try setting the execute permissions on the directory

```
chmod u+xr,go-rwx ~/.ssh
```

Then see if you can run those statements again.

Comment: Such an easy and elegant command.  Worked right away on my Mac!

Comment: a drawback of `chmod u+xr,go-rwx` is how the user needs to confirm which settings need to be added or subtracted beforehand. on the other hand, it is more comprehensive than using a number code, e.g. `chmod 1755` .

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Arcege's answer, you can also use
`sudo su 
  <enter password>
 cd .ssh`
The `sudo` command (without another user name) allows you to run commands as the super-user (root), provided you are a sudo-er (your user name is in `/etc/sudoers` with the correct fields) and know the password to that sudo-enabled user.

Warning:
Operating as the super-user may be dangerous if you don't know what you're doing. You may inadvertently modify or destroy essential files. Use `sudo` with caution.

Comment: Yes, this worked when `chmod` wouldn't do the trick.